# $x e ^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ at $\infty$ to $-\infty$

Tags: integration

I want to know how to explain $\left. \left(x e ^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \right) \right|_{- \infty} ^{\infty}$ is zero?

Is it because the speed of exponentiation is greater than that of linear? How to prove? If using Bernoulli's rule, is there any other way to give an intuitive explanation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By L'Hopital,
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} xe^{-x^2/2} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{e^{x^2/2}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{xe^{x^2/2}} = 0,$$
and it follows similarly that the limit is also $0$ as $x \rightarrow -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$...=\lim_{x\to\infty }xe^{-x^2/2}-\lim_{x\to-\infty }xe^{-x^2/2}=0-0=0$$

By l'Hopital Rules:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty }xe^{-x^2/2}=\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{x}{e^{x^2/2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty }\frac{1}{xe^{x^2/2}}=\frac{1}{\infty }=0$$

Comment: You mean $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} xe^{-x^2/2} = 0$?

Answer (score -2):

$\exp -\frac{x^2}{2}$ is even.

$x$ is odd.

An odd function times an even function is odd.

The integral of an odd function over the reals is zero.

Comment: True, and offtopic for at least two different reasons.